# Why is batch_size being multiplied to GradientTape results in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, gradienttape

I'm trying to get the gradients of a loss function w.r.t to another tensor. But the gradients are being multiplied by input batch size that I feed into my model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, layers

#Sample States and Returns
states = tf.random.uniform(shape = (100,4))
returns = tf.constant([float(i) for i in range(100)])

#Creating dataset to feed data to model
states = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(states)
returns = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(returns)

#zipping datasets into one
batch_size = 4
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((states, returns)).batch(batch_size)

model = Sequential([layers.Dense(128, input_shape =(4,), activation = tf.nn.relu), 
                    layers.Dense(1, activation = tf.nn.tanh)])

for state_batch, returns_batch in dataset:
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        values = model(state_batch)
        loss =  returns_batch - values  
    
    # d_loss/d_values should be -1.0,  but i'm getting -1.0 * batch_size
    print(tape.gradient(loss,values))
    break
```

```
Output:
tf.Tensor(
[[-4.]
 [-4.]
 [-4.]
 [-4.]], shape=(4, 1), dtype=float32)

Expected Output:
tf.Tensor(
[[-1.]
 [-1.]
 [-1.]
 [-1.]], shape=(4, 1), dtype=float32)
```

From the code, you can see that `loss = returns - values`. So it should be `d_loss/d_values = -1.0` , but the result I'm getting is `d_loss/d_values = -1.0 * batch_size`. Someone please point out why this is happening? How can I get the real results?

colab link : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x4pyGJ5ccRVSMzDAeLzcPXRtO7cNFnJf?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```py
loss = returns_batch - values
```

Here, `returns_batch` has shape `(4,)`, but `values` has shape `(4, 1)`. The subtraction operation broadcasts the tensors, resulting in a `loss` tensor that has shape `(4, 4)`, with four repeated columns. For this reason, changing a single value of `values` affects four elements of `returns_batch`, hence the scaled gradient value. You can fix it for example like this:

```py
loss = returns_batch - tf.squeeze(values, axis=1)
```

Comment: I've been trying to train a PPO rl agent which never learns. Took me two days and a lot of tensorboard visualization to figure out that there was problem with gradients. Now the agent is learning with your simple fix. I feel so stupid. Thanks a lot :) @jdehesa

Comment: @UchihaMadara Glad it helped, no reason to feel stupid, it is extremely easy to make that kind of mistake, I keep doing it myself every once in a while. It is probably even easier with Keras in particular since, when the output dimension is one, you can feed it a tensor of shape `(batch_size,)` as training label and it will accept it (because Keras will interpret it as a batch of single-feature vectors), but the actual output will have shape `(batch_size, 1)`. Convenient but sometimes dangerous, I guess :)